# Interceptar el servidor caido

Tags: flutter

[image: Captura del código]

Estoy haciendo una app que realiza una petición http. Teniendo el servidor activo, funciona perfecto. Ahora, bajando el servidor y corriendo la app, me genera un error, el cual entiendo que no se podría conectar, lo que quiero es interceptar la falta de conexión al servidor y enviar un AlterDialog. COMO PUEDO HACERLO??? Gracias!!!

Comment: Puedes proporcionar el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento

Comment: Cualquier petición HTTP que realices debes envolverla en un try-catch, ya que si falla te puede lanzar una SocketException. En tu código pasa exactamente eso: se intenta realizar la petición HTTP, el método de la librería http no encuentra acceso a Internet, y te escupe de vuelta una SocketException, deteniendo la ejecución de tu programa.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que has hecho una llamada a un servicio para obtener los datos de una persona y la url es:

```
String url = 'ruta/service/persons'
```

Una vez que tú haces la consulta por medio del método `http get` te debe retornar algo:

```
Future<String> obtenerPersona(int idUser) async {
   String? persona;
    try {
     final peticion = await http.get(Uri.parse("${url}/$idUser");
     
    } catch (e){
        rethrow;
    }
  return persona!;
}
```

Cuando tú haces la llamada, el servidor te va a responder con un `statusCode` lo que te dirá si la consulta fue exitosa o ocurrió algo al momento de llamarla:

```
Future<String> obtenerPersona(int idUser) async {
   String? persona;
    try {
     final peticion = await http.get(Uri.parse("${url}/$idUser");
     //VALIDAMOS LA RESPUESTA DEL SERVICIO
     //CODIGOS DE 200 => correcto
     //CÓDIGO 502 => SV caído
     if(peticion.statusCode > 199 && peticion.statusCode < 300){
          persona = peticion.body;
       } else if(peticion.statusCode == 502){
         //MUESTRAS EL CUADRO DE DIÁLOGO
      } else{
      
      }
    } catch (e){
        rethrow;
    }
  //esta variable la puedes decodificar con un json.decode o jsonDecode
  return persona!;
}
```